# What are the pros and cons of leveraging OpenAI's ChatGPT for data analysis?

Tags: chatgpt, openai, analysis

I have been using OpenAI's [ChatGPT 4](https://chat.openai.com) for some time now, for a variety of medical, educational, scholarly, and statistical tasks.

I find it very informative, detailed, and flexible, and it can provide meaningful guidance on data analysis. Furthermore, it can perform some statistical analyses itself.  (see for instance this intriguing example:

[image: example])

However, this begets a key question for all those interesting in sound and accountable data analysis: **what are the pros and cons of leveraging OpenAI's ChatGPT for data analysis?**

Comment: The sting lies in your question. You clearly have enough statistical expertise to regard this as a good example, but equally one good example falls far short of a full analysis of the range of possibilities. I will comment obliquely: Those who don't need this kind of support won't seek it, and those who seek it may not be able to tell what is good advice and what isn't.

Comment: In this case, the explanation of P-values would cause discomfort to many experienced statistical people. How far it makes sense to people new to the field I can't say. In one strong sense, the issues are far from new because they arise in getting help from any source whatsoever (teacher, textbook, mentor, supervisor, fellow student) with limited or inaccurate grasp of statistics.

Comment: @NickCox re: p-value explanation, are you talking about the "Interpret Results" section? Would you mind making explicit what the problem is? This sounds like the standard Neyman-Pearsonian interpretation of a p-value to me.

Comment: There could be a long forum discussion on this, but top of my personal list is a presumption or implication that a P-value is useful mainly -- or even only -- insofar as it leads to a decision about significance (yes or no). I use P-values as indications.  As the question is "What is the most appropriate approach...?" so much emphasis on a significance test is to me excessive, although -- credit where credit is due -- mention of confidence intervals and graphical presentation is welcome. To be clear, I have never used ChatGPT but that doesn't rule out comment on  its results.

Comment: Although the question is to me undoubtedly interesting and important, I fear it's too broad to be a good topic here.